# How do you determine if a String is a palindrome?

Tags: java, string, palindrome

How do you test if a given String is a palindrome in Java, without using any methods that do it all for me?

Comment: The community really isn't here to just give you complete code. Show us what you've tried and we will help you.

Also this sounds like homework to me, but I'm not going to tag it yet.

Comment: What does it mean "without using APIs?"  If it means what I think it means, then this problem is impossible.

Answer (score 6):

```
String palindrome = "..." // from elsewhere
boolean isPalindrome = palindrome.equals(new StringBuilder(palindrome).reverse().toString());
```

Comment: I guess that "without using API'S" means: without using for example `StringBuilder.reverse()`.

Answer (score 5):

```
public boolean checkPalindrome(string word){

for(int i=0 ; i < word.length()/2;i++)
{
  if(word.charAt(i) ! = word.charAt(word.length()-1-i))

      return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noel's solution is actually better. But if it's for homework, you might want to do this:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = word.length() -1;

    while (left < right) {
        if (word.charAt(left) != word.charAt(right)) 
            return false;

        left++;
        right--;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java in-place palindrome check:

```
public static final boolean isPalindromeInPlace(String string) {
    char[] array = string.toCharArray();
    int length = array.length-1;
    int half = Math.round(array.length/2);
    char a,b;
    for (int i=length; i>=half; i--) {
        a = array[length-i];
        b = array[i];
        if (a != b) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String str="iai";

StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(str);
String str1=sb.reverse().toString();
if(str.equals(str1)){
   System.out.println("polindrom");
} else {
   System.out.println("not polidrom");
}
```

Comment: -1 Exactly the same answer as Noel's.